# Concatenating absolute paths with the Pathname class

Tags: ruby, pathname

I am working on a project where I have a dynamically determined mount point and am provided a set of absolute paths to do work on on the target volume.  Since these files don't exist yet, I am using the Pathname class to handle the filename manipulations.  However, Pathname seems to be doing something a bit clever when it comes to concatenating paths that have the same root. I have observed the following behavior:

```
p1 = Pathname.new('/foo/bar')                         # #<Pathname:/foo/bar>
p2 = Pathname.new('/baz/quux')                        # #<Pathname:/baz/quux>
p3 = p1 + p2                                          # #<Pathname:/baz/quux>
p4 = p1.join p2.relative_path_from(Pathname.new('/')) # #<Pathname:/foo/bar/baz/quux>
p5 = Pathname.new(p1.to_s.concat p2)                  # #<Pathname:/foo/bar/baz/quux>
```

So with p4 and p5, I am able to get the behavior I wanted, but the constructions are a little contrived.  Is there a cleaner way to do this?

Answer (score 5):

It's fairly easy to work around Ruby's odd behavior here using string manipulation.

Borrowing the OP's example...

```
p1 = Pathname.new('/foo/bar')
p2 = '/baz/quux'
p1 + p2.sub(/\A\//, '')
# => #<Pathname:/foo/bar/baz/quux>
```

**Caveat:** The second `p2` must be a `String` in order for the `sub` operation to occur. You can easily convert a `Pathname` object using `#to_s`.

```
Pathname.new('/some/path/').to_s
# => "/some/path"
```

Answer (score 4):

From the [fine manual](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/pathname/rdoc/Pathname.html#method-i-2B):

> **+(other)**
>
> Pathname#+ appends a *pathname fragment* to this one to produce a new Pathname object.
>
> ```
> p1 = Pathname.new("/usr")      # Pathname:/usr
> p2 = p1 + "bin/ruby"           # Pathname:/usr/bin/ruby
> p3 = p1 + "/etc/passwd"        # Pathname:/etc/passwd
> ```

Emphasis mine. The `+` operator for Pathname is specified to append *pathname fragments* but a pathname with a leading slash is not a fragment. The documentation doesn't explicitly specify what is supposed to happen if you try to add two pathnames or add a non-fragment to a Pathname but the examples imply that you're seeing the expected behavior.

Comment: shouldn't we add each directory separately - "bin" + "ruby" - for crossplatform reasons.

Comment: @shabunc: That would be a better habit to get into, I was just quoting the documentation.